# Does T-SQL have a mechanism for reading rows as of beginning of transaction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, isolation-level

I've been unable to find docs that address this, and I've tried both the serializable and snapshot isolation levels to no benefit.

I am interested in querying a table during a transaction where I've modified the table in the transaction, but my query is not aware of those data modifications.

I'm sure I could carefully sequence things and potentially use temp tables to accomplish my functionality, but if there's a query hint or isolation level that simplifies my code I'd like to use it!

Comment: If you mean to read the rows that you have modified and thus they are locked for other transactions, there is nothing special to do because they are always available for your transaction. If you mean to read the previous version of the rows before you updated them, then you cannot do that, and if you need to do it, then add an `output into` clause to your `update` and capture the `deleted.*` columns you are interested into a table variable.

Comment: I meant the latter... thanks for pointing out that output into clause, it may go a long way towards what I was trying to accomplish!

Comment: Also @GSerg if the output clause is the closest I can get to my ask, you should make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You could do this with 2 different connections, with the first starting transaction in the snapshot isolation level and the other performing the modifications. Queries executed on the first connection will return data as it existed when the snapshot transaction began.

Comment: True enough, but I'm needing access to the old data while in the transaction that's making the changes, so I don't think using 2 connections will work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular table, you don't have access to the previous versions of the rows that you have modified in the current transaction.

If the table is indeed a regular table, you can [add the `output` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#aa-using-update-with-the-output-clause) to your `update` statement to capture the previous version:

```sql
declare @t table(...);

update ...
set ...
output deleted.column1, ... into @t;
```

If the table is a temporal table through, you [can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15) access the previous version:

```sql
declare @before_update datetime = getdate();

update ... ;

select ... from table ... for system_time as of @before_update;
```

Note this may not be quite what you want, given the concurrent nature of SQL Server. It might return you data that is just a bit too old, if another transaction gets in between of your `= getdate()` and `update`.